# How to write the constructor for a template class that wraps a container where the container can be both an array or a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I wish to have a general template class that allows the user to pass the container to use:

```
template<class Container>
struct Sum
{
  Container m_terms;
...
```

Other classes will derive from that, for example,

```
class MySum : public Sum<std::vector<int>>
{
...
```

or

```
class MySum4 : public Sum<std::array<int, 4>>
{
...
```

The containers need to be initialized from the constructor.
My idea at first was to use `std::initializer_list`, for example,

```
MySum ms{1, 2, 3, 4};
```

which would require the following constructors to be added:

```
template<class Container>
struct Sum
{
  Container m_terms;

  Sum(std::initializer_list<typename Container::value_type> const& il) :
    m_terms(il) { }
...
```

```
class MySum : public Sum<std::vector<int>>
{
  using Sum<std::vector<int>>::Sum;
...
```

but then how can I get MySum4 to work too? An `array` doesn't take a `std::initializer_list<>`.

Here is more complete code that shows the compiler error:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/CZW3YaKdInwZZD8e

Comment: "*Other classes will derive from that*" Don't do that. Just make them members.

Comment: Avoid deep inheritance

Comment: @NicolBolas I had that in the past two weeks, but the Sum class has six virtual functions that need access to the container (and the type it stores). It got really messy; by moving the container to the base class my code cleaned up DRAMATICALLY - except for this one problem that two of the derived classes use an array.

Comment: C++11 or C++17? In C++17 aggregate initialization makes this a breeze.

Comment: What is the base sum type *for* and what are the derived mysum/mysum4 types *for*?  Are you really passing around `Sum<std::vector<int>>` pointers whose derived type is `MySum` and in other cases it is `MyOtherSum`?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, here is (probably) the final version-ish of what I was working on: https://github.com/CarloWood/quantum/blob/master/src/formula.h

Comment: Oh, the test case where this used (tested): https://github.com/CarloWood/quantum/blob/master/src/formula_test.cxx

Answer (score 1):

What about using old C-style arrays and delegating constructors?

Something as follows

```
  template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
  Sum (T const (& il)[N], std::index_sequence<Is...> const)
        : m_terms{{il[Is]...}}
   { }

  template <typename T, std::size_t N>
  Sum (T const (& il)[N]) : Sum(il, std::make_index_sequence<N>{})
   { }
```

But you have to add a couple of braces calling it

```
struct MySum : Sum<std::vector<int>>
{
  MySum(int t0, int t1, int t2, int t3) : Sum<std::vector<int>>{{t0, t1, t2, t3}} { }
}; // ..........................................................^..............^

struct MySum4 : Sum<std::array<int, 4>>
{
  MySum4(int t0, int t1, int t2, int t3) : Sum<std::array<int, 4>>{{t0, t1, t2, t3}} { }
}; // .............................................................^..............^
```

Comment: Impressive... Give me a day to digest this (have to run to a chess tournament now, and sleeping afterwards first). Already tested it in wandbox though and it works :).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is applying the variadic template with double braces for the ctor `Sum::Sum` as follows.
This double braces enable us to set `Container` to `std::array`:

```
template<typename Container>
struct Sum
{
  Container m_terms;

  template<typename ...Args>
  Sum(Args&&... args) : m_terms{{std::forward<Args>(args)...}} { }

  void print()
  {
      for (auto&& term : m_terms){
        std::cout << ' ' << term;
      }

      std::cout << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Then you can do like this:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LgHWljk5YMQoNofw)

```
struct MySum : Sum<std::vector<int>>
{
    MySum(int t0, int t1, int t2, int t3) : Sum<std::vector<int>>{t0, t1, t2, t3} { }
};

struct MySum4 : Sum<std::array<int, 4>>
{
    MySum4(int t0, int t1, int t2, int t3) : Sum<std::array<int, 4>>{t0, t1, t2, t3} { }
};

struct MySumSet : Sum<std::set<int>>
{
    MySumSet(int t0, int t1, int t2, int t3) : Sum<std::set<int>>{t0, t1, t2, t3} { }
};

struct MySumList : Sum<std::list<int>>
{
    MySumList(int t0, int t1, int t2, int t3) : Sum<std::list<int>>{t0, t1, t2, t3} { }
};

int main()
{  
    MySum s(1, 2, 3, 4);
    s.print();

    MySum4 s4(1, 2, 3, 4);
    s4.print();
    static_assert(s4.m_terms.size() == 4);

    MySumSet ss(1, 2, 3, 4);
    ss.print();

    MySumList sl(1, 2, 3, 4);
    sl.print();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness I wanted to answer my own question with a method that I only realized later is possible; namely, simply allow the caller to pass the container (whose type it knows) as an rvalue. And to my surprise this then works with all containers when passing double braces!

```
struct Sum
{
  Container m_terms;

  Sum(Container&& terms) : m_terms(std::move(terms)) { }

  void print()
  {
    for (auto&& term : m_terms)
      std::cout << ' ' << term;
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
};
```

And the [**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TOBRQ3Knv0WRcLRt)

```
struct MySum : Sum<std::vector<int>>
{
  MySum(int t0, int t1, int t2, int t3) : Sum<std::vector<int>>{{t0, t1, t2, t3}} { }
};

struct MySum4 : Sum<std::array<int, 4>>
{
  MySum4(int t0, int t1, int t2, int t3) : Sum<std::array<int, 4>>{{t0, t1, t2, t3}} { }
};

struct MySumSet : Sum<std::set<int>>
{
    MySumSet(int t0, int t1, int t2, int t3) : Sum<std::set<int>>{{t0, t1, t2, t3}} { }
};

struct MySumList : Sum<std::list<int>>
{
    MySumList(int t0, int t1, int t2, int t3) : Sum<std::list<int>>{{t0, t1, t2, t3}} { }
};

int main()
{  
    MySum s(1, 2, 3, 4);
    s.print();

    MySum4 s4(1, 2, 3, 4);
    s4.print();
    static_assert(s4.m_terms.size() == 4);

    MySumSet ss(1, 2, 3, 4);
    ss.print();

    MySumList sl(1, 2, 3, 4);
    sl.print();
}
```